# INSTALL_PARSE_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.sudoku">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            />

        <activity android:name=".GameMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have this error that won't go away and I can't figure out what's wrong.
I checked my code and nothing is capitalized or mistyped. what is wrong with this document or is there another document that may be causing the error?

Comment: Is your package name correct?

Answer (score 0):

`meta-data` elements must have a `value` or a `resource` attribute, `name` alone is not enough.